# Visual Studio 2010 Publish Web feature not including all DLLs

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, build-process, msdeploy

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 application.

- Web project contains a reference to SomeProject
- SomeProject contains references to ExternalAssembly1 and ExternalAssembly2.
- SomeProject explicitly calls into ExternalAssembly1, but NOT ExternalAssembly2.
- ExternalAssembly1 calls into ExternalAssembly2

When I perform a local build everything is cool.  All DLLs are included in the bin\debug folder.  The problem is that when I use the Publish Web command in Visual Studio 2010, it deploys everything except ExternalAssembly2.

It appears to ignore assemblies that aren't directly used (remember, ExternalAssembly2 is only used by ExternalAssembly1).

Is there any way I can tell Visual Studio 2010 to include ExternalAssembly2?

I can write a dummy method that calls into ExternalAssembly2.  This does work, but I really don't want to have dummy code for the sole purpose of causing VS2010 to publish the DLL.

Comment: Have you tried this in VS 11? I just tried it out and it looked like it was working. If you find that it is still not working can you email me at sayedha{at}(microsoftDOTcom)? Thanks!
FYI if you find that a lot of assemblies are not making it into bin\ then Rebuild your solution in the same Build Configuration used on the publish dialog, then publish again. That was another bug which has already been fixed.

Comment: Feel free to disregard my previous comment, it was user error on my part. I can now repro this and I realize it is an issue. At this point I'm not sure what can be done here but I want you guys to know that I am looking into this.

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi thank you for following up

Comment: I was stung by this today, on a production server. It seems strange that it *isn't* copying the contents of the site bin folder, as that contains the correct assemblies.

Comment: I can confirm this is an issue for my Silverlight 5 project also

Comment: I have a similar problem where Visual Studio 2012 fails to package one of the assembly required for worker role project. This assembly, calling it as a.dll is resource assembly and linked to another assembly b.dll using /linkresource option. I am referencing b.dll in my worker role project.  I have another website project where I am referencing b.dll. Here VS2012 happily packages both b.dll and a.dll. So it's definitely a bug in VS2012.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

None of these answers are sufficient in my mind.  This does seem to be a genuine bug.  I will update this response if I ever find a non-hack solution, or Microsoft fixes the bug.

Update:

Doesn't seem promising.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/731303/publish-web-feature-not-including-all-dlls

Answer (score 7):

I am having this same problem (different assemblies though).  If I reference the assemblies in my web project, then they will get included in the publish output, but they should be included anyway because they are indirect dependencies:

Web Project ---> Assembly A ---> Assembly B

On build, assemblies A and B are outputed to the \bin folder.  On publish, only assembly A is outputed to the publish folder.

I have tried changing the publish settings to include *all* files in the web project, but then I have files in my publish output that shouldn't be deployed.

This seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I agree.  For now I think I'm going to leave in the dummy method that just calls into each DLL I need to be published.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with VS2010 and a WCF Service Application.

It turns out that if your (directly or indirectly) referenced DLL's are deployed to GAC, the VS publishing feature excludes them. Once I removed the assemblies from GAC, publishing feature started working as expected.

I guess VS is assuming that if your assemblies can be located in GAC on the machine you build, they will be located in GAC on the target machine as well. At least in my case this assumption is false.

Answer (score 3):

My tests show that the external assemblies get published when I have a reference on them in the web project. I do not have to write any dummy code to make it work. This seems acceptable to me.

I agree with Nicholas that this seems to be a bug in visual studio. At least it escapes me what the reason for the behavior could be.

Comment: It's still a hack though.  I shouldn't have to reference assemblies in my Web project that aren't used in the Web project.  What happens in 6 months when we decide to cleanup unused assembly references?

Answer (score 3):

I have created this issue as a bug on Microsoft Connect. If anyone experiencing it could vote it up https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/637071/publish-web-feature-not-including-all-dlls then hopefully we'll get something done about it.

Comment: Looks like they've closed it as *Not Reproducible* since no one had a chance to upload a sample solution. I've also encountered this issue, will try to create a small "repro" solution for them to investigate.

Comment: Guys this I'm not sure why the connect website is showing this as Not Reproducible. In the comments I did mention (about last week way after the previous comment) that I couldn't repro it but I asked for more info. I am actively investigating this. I will work to get the status updated on Connect.

Answer (score 2):

If you go into the ExternalAssembly2 reference property list and change the "Copy Local" to "True" i think that might solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that's already set (which is why the local build works).  This doesn't solve the publishing issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are watching this still but I found the solution (I had the exact same issue) via [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). Under "build action" for the file choose "Content" that should include it in the list of files publish brings over.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it out when I get a chance and update accordingly

Comment: This appears to work, but again, if VS2010 can figure out what it needs to copy to bin\debug to run, it should use the same logic (at least for the minimum set of files) when it publishes.

Comment: How does this work for referenced assemblies? There is no 'Build action' option for a reference.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a new Connect bug here https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/731303/publish-web-feature-not-including-all-dlls

I've also attached a solution and detailed steps to reproduce this issue. Lets hope this time they won't close it as Can't Reproduce.

Vote for this connect issue if you experience the missing dll problem.

Answer (score 2):

Copy local did the trick. I had an issue that the Newtonsoft.Json assembly get included in the deploymeny package. Copy local was set to false.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same type of issue with a web project. I have a web project that references assembly A which references assembly B. It worked fine for some time but today it was broken. I did a rebuild of the solution and this time it deployed everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem today. I published my web project and realized that not all of the reference DLL's were there. In particular, the indirect DLL references.

It turns out that the directory in which I was publishing to was out of disk space (network share). I had just enough space to publish all the files except for few indirect reference DLL's. The sad part is that VS08 didn't throw any errors. It just published the files are usual. I cleared out some HDD space and everything worked fine.

I didn't find the HDD space issue until I tried to manually move the DLL's over.

Answer (score 1):

in my case it is quite tricky.
Reference to ExternalAssembly2 is not required to Build the project but vital for run-time since we use reflection to configure Unity container.
So, I delete the reference - build the project successfully, but get run-time error.
If I preserve the reference I can Build and Run the application but I cannot Publish it with ExternalAssembly2 - get run-time exception as well.
This is happen because of internal VS2010 assemblies optimization.

So, what we can do here?
1. Put some unrequired peice of code to use any ExternalAssembly2's class.
2. escape from reflection and use static assemblies linking.

Hope this helps to smbd.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and this is a VS2010 bug if there's a reference link like:
Web Project --> custom project --> assembly1 -->(indirectly) assembly2.

For now I find if I reference the Assembly1 in the web project, then assembly2 is included in the bin folder.
So I had to add an additional reference link like:
Web project --> assembly1 -->(indirectly) assembly2.
Then VS can recognize assembly2 and include its dll file in publish action.